# Converting a String to Numbers in an Excel File with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel

I have an HTML Table Element that I read the data from and export into an Excel file. All the data is exported correctly, its just that Excel does not recognize the cell values as I intend them to be recognized and formatted. What I need is the all of the cell values with '$' to be recognized as numbers and not text. So, for example a cell value with '8.50' should be recognized as the number $8.50 and not as text.  I have tried explicitly setting the cellObj.type property to ExcelJS.ValueType.Number for cells containing prices but the excel file still recognized those cell values as text.This is how my code looks so far, what can I do to have the cell values be properly recognized as numbers?

```
async exportCsv(el: HTMLElement) {
  console.log('exportCsv called');
  let element = el.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Data');

  const tableRows = Array.from(element.rows).map(row => Array.from(row.cells).map(cell => cell.textContent));
  worksheet.addRows(tableRows);

  worksheet.getColumn(1).width = 28;

  tableRows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
      const cellObj = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex + 1).getCell(cellIndex + 1);

      // Skip the cell if it contains the character 'x'
      if (cell.includes('x')) {
        return;
      }
    else if (cell.startsWith('$')) {
        const priceValue = parseFloat(cell.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
        cellObj.value = priceValue;
        cellObj.type = ExcelJS.ValueType.Number; 
        cellObj.numFmt = '\\$0.00';
      }
      else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(cell))) {
        cellObj.value = parseFloat(cell);
        cellObj.numFmt = '0.00';
      }
    });
  });
}
```

For more context, the first row of the table contains all the cell values I need to be recognized as numbers and they look like this:

Price: $8.50 | $9.00 | $9.25 | $9.50

In the Excel file, for all the cells containing these $, there is a green carat on the top left of each cell indicating that the number is stored as text.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel if you type in a cell "$8.25" the cell format remain General, which means that it accept it as a String. To get a Currency format, type in only the value, and change Number Format to Currency, and configure the format of the number as you like.
So, try to add the $ expression to the RegExp, and set the valuetype as Currency and the numberformat which is in Excel [$$-409]#,##0.00 for the USD.

or you can try

```
cellObj.value =Number(String(cellObj.value).slice(1))
```

in the else if statement